# How to initialize a variable number of arrays/dictionaries?

Tags: python

If i have a variable number of arrays, how do I initialize/work on them?

```
x = int(input())

for i in range(x):
    dict_i = {}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. I'd rather go for a dict of dicts.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - I cannot think of any reason why someone would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would generate a list of dictionaries. You should be able to access them afterwards based on index.

```
x = int(input())

dictionaries = []
for i in range(x):
    dictionaries.append(dict())

print(dictionaries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use `globals` and `setattr`:

```py
x = int(input())

for i in range(x):
    globals()[f"dict_{i}"] = {}
```

But I can't think of why you would want to do this at all.

Comment: i was thinking of doing a all-possible-combination analysis of a set of related variable. I always start thinking of the pointer system and I end up thinking of how to do this

Answer (score -2):

you just can make it as below

```
x = int(input())
y= [{}]*x
```

Comment: This won't work due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/1904146